# Javascript: finding all objects in an array which have certain properties and values

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects. Each object has a boolean property called `available` on it, along with an arbitrary number of other properties. I know the `available` property exists, but I have no idea what the other properties are. For instance:

```
var myObjects = [
    {color:100, size:12, available:true},
    {color:100, size:13, available:false},
    {color:100, size:18, available:true},
    {color:110, size:12, available:true},
    {length:86, available:true},
]
```

I need a function `isAvailable()` which can take any attribute:value pairs and return those objects which match and are available. For instance, if I asked it for available objects with a color of `100` it would return an array consisting of the first and third object only:

```
>> isAvailable({color:100})
Array [ {color:100, size:12, available:true}, {color:100, size:18, available:true} ]
```

But if I asked it for objects with a color of `100` and a length of `86`, or just a size of `13`, it would return an empty array.

```
>> isAvailable({color:100, length:86}) // there are no objects with both of these properties
Array [ ]
>> isAvailable({size:13}) // there is a matching object, but it is not available
Array [ ]
```

I have a function working, but it isn't very pretty. Not being very experienced with javascript, I'm not sure if there is a better way to go about this.

```
function isAvailable(options) {
    var availableObjects = [];
    // get the number of objects
    var numObjects = myObjects.length;
    // get the number of options that were given
    var numOptions = Object.keys(options).length;
    // loop through each object
    for (var i = 0; i < numObjects; i++) {
        var thisObject = myObjects[i];
        // default the matching to false
        var match = false;
        // loop through each option and check if the current object has the option and, if so, if the values are the same.
        for (var x = 0; x < numOptions; x++) {
            var thisOption = Object.keys(options)[x]
            if (thisObject.hasOwnProperty(thisOption) && thisObject[thisOption] == options[thisOption]) {
                match = true;
            } else {
                match = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (match == true && thisObject.available == true) {
            availableObjects.push(thisObject);
        }
    }
    return availableObjects;
}
```

Can anybody offer any feedback on this? thank you.

Comment: Check out `.filter` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: sounds like underscore's `.find()` method

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()` and `every()` to return desired result.

```js
var myObjects = [
  {color:100, size:12, available:true},
  {color:100, size:13, available:false},
  {color:100, size:18, available:true},
  {color:110, size:12, available:true},
  {length:86, available:true},
]

function isAvailable(obj) {
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  return myObjects.filter(function(e) {
    return keys.every(function(k) {
      return e.available && e.hasOwnProperty(k) && obj[k] == e[k]
    })
  })
}

console.log(isAvailable({color:100}))
console.log(isAvailable({color:100, length:86}))
console.log(isAvailable({size:13}))
```

Comment: Better cache `Object.keys(obj)` outside the `filter`.

Comment: ...and make `myObjects` a parameter, don't use a global

Answer (score 0):

You can use array .filter() method. For older browsers you can use Lodash

```
myObjects.filter(function(x) { return x["available"] === true && x["color"] === 100 })
```

Comment: That's not what they asked for. `isAvailable` should accept a dynamic filter object.